# When a couple goes for a vacation, only two of them, is there a special word for that

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

When a newly married couple goes on vacation with just two of them, it's called a `honeymoon`. But say a couple goes on vacation together, with just two of them, after 5 years or more, does it have any special name? The difference here is that the couple is not traveling with any of their friends

Comment: Always good to tell us why you think there would be a word for that.  Commonly this is because there is a specific term in your language.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd say the answer is no, there is no special word for that.

Sometimes when a married couple go on a trip that is intended to be romantic, it is called a "second honeymoon". But I wouldn't use that term for any vacation for just the two of them.

If anyone else on here can think of a general term for this, I'll gladly yield.

Comment: Indeed.  For a couple, taking a vacation together is the default action, and so doesn't have a special term.